How to build a cffi extension for inclusion in binary python wheel with uv
I am migrating a library of mine to use uv to manage the package. My package, however, includes a C extension that is wrapped and compiled through CFFI (there's a build script for this).
Below is the current version of pyproject.toml that fails to run the build script and, If I build the extension manually, uv build --wheel does not include the _readdbc.so file in the wheel.
[project]
authors = [
    {name = "Flavio Codeco Coelho", email = "fccoelho@gmail.com"},
    {name = "Sandro Loch", email = "es.loch@gmail.com"},
]
license = {text = "AGPL-3.0"}
requires-python = "<4,>=3.9"
dependencies = [
    "dbfread<3,>=2.0.7",
    "tqdm<5,>=4.64.0",
    "cffi<2,>=1.15.1",
    "pyyaml>=6",
    "setuptools>=75.6.0",
]
name = "pyreaddbc"
version = "1.1.0"
description = "pyreaddbc package"
readme = "README.md"
classifiers = [
    "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
    "Intended Audience :: Developers",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU Affero General Public License v3 or later (AGPLv3+)",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11",
]

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["pyreaddbc"]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"


[build]
default = ["python", "-m", "./pyreaddbc/_build_readdbc.py"] # this script never runs


[tool.black]
line-length = 79
skip-string-normalization = true
target-version = ["py39", "py310", "py311", "py312"]
exclude = "docs/"

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = [
    "pytest<9.0.0,>=8.1.1",
    "pandas<3.0.0,>=2.1.0",
]

[project.urls]
Repository = "https://github.com/AlertaDengue/pyreaddbc"


What am I missing?

After a few days, bumping my head against the lack of specific documentation about this, here is the final form of a pyproject.toml that works :
[project]
authors = [
    { name = "Flavio Codeco Coelho", email = "fccoelho@gmail.com" },
    { name = "Sandro Loch", email = "es.loch@gmail.com" },
]
license = { text = "AGPL-3.0" }
requires-python = "<4,>=3.9"
dependencies = [
    "dbfread<3,>=2.0.7",
    "tqdm<5,>=4.64.0",
    "cffi<2,>=1.15.1",
    "pyyaml>=6",
    "setuptools>=75.6.0",
]
name = "pyreaddbc"
version = "1.2.0"
description = "pyreaddbc package"
readme = "README.md"
classifiers = [
    "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
    "Intended Audience :: Developers",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU Affero General Public License v3 or later (AGPLv3+)",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11",
]

[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = ["pyreaddbc"]
ext-modules = [
    {name = "pyreaddbc._readdbc",  sources = ["pyreaddbc/_readdbc.c", "pyreaddbc/c-src/blast.c"],     include-dirs = ["pyreaddbc", "pyreaddbc/c-src"]}#,    libraries = ["readdbc"],    library-dirs = ["pyreaddbc"]},
]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61", "cffi"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[build]
default = ["python", "-m", "./pyreaddbc/_build_readdbc.py"]

[tool.black]
line-length = 79
skip-string-normalization = true
target-version = ["py39", "py310", "py311", "py312"]
exclude = "docs/"

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = [
    "pytest<9.0.0,>=8.1.1",
    "pandas<3.0.0,>=2.1.0",
]

[project.urls]
Repository = "https://github.com/AlertaDengue/pyreaddbc"


I hope this will help other people needing to automate CFFI extension build using uv.
